# Highcharts multiple x-Axis without multiple series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axes, multiple-axes

This fiddle uses multiple series and displays an axis for each of them.  Is it possible to use a single series to make several Axes? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/

```
xAxis:[{
        categories:setup.x_mixed,
        maxZoom:5,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        labels:{
          "enabled":setup.categories_label,
          "y":1,
          "style":{
            "fontSize":13,
            "color":"#999",
            fontFamily:"'helvetica neue',helvetica",
            whiteSpace:"nowrap",
            textOverflow:"clip",
            width:"100%",
            marginTop:legendSpacing
          },
          formatter:function () {
            return this.value.split("|")[0]
          }
        },
        lineColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        tickWidth:0,
        offset:0
      }, { // Secondary yAxis
        categories:setup.x_mixed,
        maxZoom:5,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        labels:{
          "enabled":setup.categories_label,
          "y":16,
          "style":{
            "fontSize":13,
            "color":"#999",
            fontFamily:"'helvetica neue',helvetica",
            whiteSpace:"nowrap",
            textOverflow:"clip",
            width:"100%",
            marginTop:legendSpacing
          },
          formatter:function () {
            return this.value.split("|")[1]
          }
        },
        lineColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        tickWidth:0,
        offset:0

        }],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use linkedTo paramtetr on extra axis http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.linkedTo

Answer (score 2):

its pretty simple,

declare 2 xAxis same like the yAxis you mentioned in the example with one of them as 
`opposite:true`

As you have only one series set the second axis extremes same as the first one using getExtremes() and setExtremes(), as shown in this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/W43Zb/

Hope this will help you